# Logging from shells script with log4sh

Tags: bash, shell, logs

I am trying to send an SMTP email using log4sh. All other logging like stdout, file appender are working but the smtp thing is not working.

**log4sh.properties** :

```
log4sh.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, smtp, file
log4sh.appender.smtp=SMTPAppender
log4sh.appender.smtp.Threshold=DEBUG
log4sh.appender.smtp.To=myemail@gmail.com
log4sh.appender.smtp.Subject=This is a test subject
log4sh.appender.smtp.layout=PatternLayout
log4sh.appender.smtp.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-5p] %F - %m%n
```

Below is the code that works for stdout and file but not for smtp :

```
logger_error "This is a test";
```

Below is the link for log4sh :

http://svn.code.sf.net/p/log4sh/svn/trunk/source/1.5/doc/log4sh.html

Answer (score 0):

By default, all linux software don't dirrectly send email, instead you should properly configure a SMTP relay on you system by configuring properly a mail server like postfix.

You can easely find proper documentation on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to send email directly using SMTP it works. But I want to make ti work with log4sh.

Comment: check if your mail are not sutck on the mail queue with `mailq` command

Answer (score 0):

There's good amount of detail on logging for shell scripts via global varaibles of shell. We can emulate the similar kind of logging in shell script: http://www.cubicrace.com/2016/03/log-tracing-mechnism-for-shell-scripts.html

The post has details on introdducing log levels like INFO , DEBUG, ERROR. Tracing details like script entry, script exit, function entry, function exit.

Sample Log:
[image]